# Laravel Eloquent performance issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

when I use Eloquent to get data, and found out some performance issue

In my case, I use laravel debugbar ( https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar ) to collect the information I need.

when I use ORM to get about 20 entries from my DB

```
$projects = Project::where('status', '=', 2)->get();
```

it took about 24MB memory usage and 250ms

but when I use the query builder as below

```
$projects = DB::table('Project')->where('status','=',2)->get();
```

the database queries and the return data are almost the same, but query builder took only 11MB memory usage and 113ms to get the data.

when the entries I need are about 200 entries, and even relate to other tables via ORM, it take almost 8000ms... and get the "Allowed memory size exhausted" error message very often..

So, I was wondering, in my condition, should I use the query builder and join other table?

Or what should I do to speed up the Eloquent performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found out where the problem is.
Actually, that issue is not really caused by Eloquent ORM but the view.
That are what I did for fixed the problem

- Eager loading:
  Since there are 4 relations in my view, so it cause N + 4 queries , I use the eager loading to fixed it. and use
- Cache:
  I use remember() to cache results.
- Cancel the Image checking:
  last things I did but most important, is to cancel the checking the Images in S3.

The page loading get a huge speed up. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, you probably need to disable query logging:

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog()
```

and use caching: http://four.laravel.com/docs/cache ,

if no significant difference then yes, you pobably just need to use query builder or even the basic:

```
DB::select(//your query here...)
```